# How to know which Dock Connector my Galaxy S2 has?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb, charging, hardware, usb-connection-mode

There are several revisions for Dock Connects/Charging Ports per model. I would like to know if there is a way to find which revision is installed on my phone without opening the device. If that's possible.

Phone: GT i9100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible as for an unrooted device. I had to open the phone to identify the port.